# What does those extra constants indicate?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

**Equation:**$$16x^2-9y^2+32x+36y-164=0$$

I know that it's a  hyperbola by reducing it to this:
$$\frac{(x+1)^2}{9}-\frac{(y-2)^2}{16}=1$$

My question is that this is different from what i have studied in school to be hyperbola's equation:

$$\frac{(x)^2}{a^2}-\frac{(y)^2}{b^2}=1$$

So why is it so?

Comment: The equation you studied in school is for a hyperbola centered at the origin. The equation you found is a hyperbola centered at $(x,y)=(-1,2)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uhh, i don't know your basics about conics. But this simply indicates about the shift of center from origin $(0,0)$ to $(-1,2)$.

Theory:
$$\frac{(x-a)^2}{A^2}-\frac{(x-b)^2}{B^2}=1$$
means that the hyperbola is now centered at $(a,b)$.

Hope It solve's your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's not any different, just that center is shifted to (-1,2).

Answer (score 0):

If the function can be expressed $f(x-a,y-b)$, $f(x,y)$ move from $(0,0)$ to $(a,b)$.